# Increasing size for Linux kernel module kfifo_alloc() which fails for 128MB

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kmalloc

We have an embedded product with quad Cortex-A53 cores, `4 GB RAM` and runs Linux Kernel v5.4 aarch64. Whole Linux currently consumes only 200MB to work, therefore I have plenty of RAM available to use.

I made a kernel module which reads 20MB/sec data from an external device through PCIe bus with chunks of 1MB. I want to push this 1MB data in the interrupt context to a FIFO works in the kernel module to be transferred later to a user space.

I looked for available fifo patterns in the Linux kernel and saw that `kfifo_alloc()` and bunch of APIs to `put and get data` already provided. This suits my purpose perfectly. As I understand it supports single producer and single consumer approach without any locking.

Required FIFO size for my application should be around 128MB. I already have 4GB RAM, therefore I thought initially that allocating such memory should have no issue.

But following code returns `ENOMEM` error unexpectedly

```c
ret = kfifo_alloc(&io_dev.streaming_dma_fifo, 128 * 1024 * 1024, GFP_KERNEL);
if (ret) {
    dev_err(&pci_dev->dev, "%s:error kfifo_alloc, ret=%d\n", __func__, ret);
    return ret;    
}
```

Then I searched the stackoverflow and saw people use `kmalloc()` complain about same thing. I think `kfifo_alloc()` function internally also uses `kmalloc()`.

Then I executed following code as suggested again in this forum:

```c
dev_info(&pci_dev->dev, "KMALLOC_SHILFT_LOW:%d, KMALLOC_SHILFT_HIGH:%d, KMALLOC_MIN_SIZE:%d, KMALLOC_MAX_SIZE:%lu\n", KMALLOC_SHIFT_LOW, KMALLOC_SHIFT_HIGH, KMALLOC_MIN_SIZE, KMALLOC_MAX_SIZE);
```

And got these outputs for my system:

```
KMALLOC_SHILFT_LOW: 7
KMALLOC_SHILFT_HIGH: 13
KMALLOC_MIN_SIZE: 128
KMALLOC_MAX_SIZE: 33554432
```

What I understand from this output is that max size that I can allocate with `kfifo_alloc()` is limited to `32MB`.

If I try to reduce the size requested for `kfifo_alloc()` from `128MB` to `32MB`, it returns no error.

Questions:

1. My FIFO RAM doesn't have any special requirements such as it should be contiguous, or atomic or  DMAable or something else. I didn't understand why kfifo_alloc() fails with 128MB while I can allocate same amount in the user space easily with `malloc()`. Is there a way to  ask `kfifo_alloc` to use `malloc` or kernel equivalent of it, instead of special `kmalloc`?
2. Is there a way to increase KMALLOC_MAX_SIZE defined as 32MB for my system?
3. What are the consequences of setting KMALLOC_MAX_SIZE as 256MB for example?
4. What is the most suggested way if my driver requires a FIFO larger than 32MB?

Comment: You could change the CONFIG_ARCH_FORCE_MAX_ORDER setting in the kernel configuration to change the MAX_ORDER constant. Not all architectures allow that to be configured (notably x86, where MAX_ORDER is fixed to the value of 10), but arm/arm64 does allow it to be configured. The value is log base 2 of the number of physically contiguous pages that can be allocated, e.g. 13 allows 2^13 (8192) physically contiguous pages or 2^13*2^12 (8192*4096 = 33554432) physically contiguous bytes to be allocated.

Comment: Contiguous memory allocations of such a size should be done differently than via `kmalloc()`. For DMA there is CMA and other memory zones that one may use. So, without those requirements one may simple call for `vmalloc()`. FYI: `kmalloc()` never guarantees to allocate anything longer than a single page (usually 4k).

Comment: Reading more of the details in question, I believe you haven't got the ideas behind `kmalloc()`, kfifo and so on, hence your stuff is already broken on the design level. What you need is to have somewhere memory buffer to which you will copy the data from your device (presumably it has to be done with DMA) and use FIFO only to point to the chunks and control the occupance of the memory.